# Adding filter with curl for github api

Tags: github, github-api

How do i add the 2fa filter in curl for the github api?[Here is an image of the documentation page, however it does not specify how to add the filter for 2fa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yu8T.png).

Thanks so much!

I have tried using a "?":
curl 
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer """
-H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" 
[https://api.github.com/orgs/"my_org_name"/members?2fa_disabled](https://api.github.com/orgs/%22my_org_name%22/members?2fa_disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the query-parameter you need is called `filter` with the value `2fa_disabled`. Therefore your curl command should look the following:

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/members?filter=2fa_disabled
```

Keep in mind that this options is only available for organization owners.

Documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/orgs/members?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-organization-members